# How can actix Actor have PyO3 Python?

Tags: python, rust, rust-actix, pyo3

I'm trying to create Actix Actor which has PyO3 Python interpreter & Py objects.

Question is what is the correct way to create python interpreter actor?

I think err caused by Actor trait defined static.
https://docs.rs/actix/0.7.4/actix/trait.Actor.html

Is there the way of Actor or Context have object require life parameter?

rust version: nightly-2018-09-04, actix version: 0.7.4

This is current code.

```rust
extern crate actix;
extern crate actix_web;
extern crate pyo3;

use actix::prelude::*;
use actix_web::{http, server, ws, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Error};
use pyo3::{Python, GILGuard, PyList};

struct WsActor<'a> {
    // addr: Addr<PyActor>,
    gil: GILGuard,
    python: Python<'a>,
    pylist: &'a PyList,
}
impl<'a> Actor for WsActor<'a> {
    type Context = ws::WebsocketContext<Self>;
}
fn attach_ws_actor(req: &HttpRequest<()>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    let python = gil.python();
    let pylist = PyList::empty(python);
    let actor = WsActor {gil, python, pylist};
    ws::start(req, actor)
}
fn main() {
    let sys = actix::System::new("example");

    server::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .resource("/ws/", |r| r.method(http::Method::GET).f(attach_ws_actor))
    }).bind("0.0.0.0:9999")
    .unwrap()
        .start();
}
```

This code can't compile with this err.

```
error[E0478]: lifetime bound not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:10
   |
15 | impl<'a> Actor for WsActor<'a> {
   |          ^^^^^
   |
note: lifetime parameter instantiated with the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 15:6
  --> src/main.rs:15:6
   |
15 | impl<'a> Actor for WsActor<'a> {
   |      ^^
   = note: but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime
```

Comment: Any reason for using version 0.5.1 instead of the newest (0.7.4)?

Comment: thx notice ! I add version info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Nikolay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288565/how-can-actix-actor-have-pyo3-python#comment91536581_52289118) says, you can store `Py<PyList>` object in `WsActor`.
To restore `PyList`, you can acquire GIL again and call `.as_ref(python)` method of `AsPyRef` trait (which `Py<T>` implements).
An example is as follows:

```rust
extern crate actix;
extern crate actix_web;
extern crate pyo3;

use actix::prelude::*;
use actix_web::{http, server, ws, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Error};
use pyo3::{Python, PyList, Py, AsPyRef};

struct WsActor {
    // addr: Addr<PyActor>,
    pylist: Py<PyList>,
}
impl Actor for WsActor {
    type Context = ws::WebsocketContext<Self>;
}
impl StreamHandler<ws::Message, ws::ProtocolError> for WsActor {
    fn handle(&mut self, _: ws::Message, _: &mut Self::Context) {
        let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
        let python = gil.python();
        let list = self.pylist.as_ref(python);
        println!("{}", list.len());
    }
}

fn attach_ws_actor(req: &HttpRequest<()>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    let python = gil.python();
    let pylist = PyList::empty(python);
    let actor = WsActor {
        pylist: pylist.into()
    };
    ws::start(req, actor)
}

fn main() {
    let sys = actix::System::new("example");

    server::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .resource("/ws/", |r| r.method(http::Method::GET).f(attach_ws_actor))
    }).bind("0.0.0.0:9999")
    .unwrap()
        .start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the [Actor trait](https://docs.rs/actix/0.7.4/actix/trait.Actor.html) is

```rust
pub trait Actor: Sized + 'static { ... }
```

which means, your lifetime `'a` must be `'static`.

Here's a little [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b5ccde9f5eb5ed694db629fdb1df8b2b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Foo: Sized + 'static {
    fn foo();
}

struct Bar<'a> {
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a i32>,
}
impl<'a> Foo for Bar<'a> { //not possible
    fn foo() {}
}

struct Baz<'a> {
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a i32>,
}
impl Foo for Baz<'static> { //possible
    fn foo() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for static lifetime explanation.

Comment: This mean Actor can't have object require life parameter ?

Comment: If so, is there any way to manage python interpreter in actix web ?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, because I haven't looked in pyo3. I think you have to figure that out by yourself :/

Comment: Now I try to create static lifetime actor. But Python interpreter object is borrowed value. So rust compiler show this error.
`error[E0597]: gil does not live long enough borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...`
GILGuard has Rc, so it can be static value...
https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/master/src/pythonrun.rs#L105

Comment: You have to acquire gil inside actor’s handler. You can store python object references in actor as Py<T> or PyObject